# display a timer in milliseconds

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timer

my code:

```
myTextBox.text = count1.currentCount.toString();
```

How would i display the current count in milliseconds?

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to convert `currentCount` to milliseconds, just multiply by 1000:

```
var currentMilliseconds = count1.currentCount * 1000;
```

Simply put, 1 second is 1000 milliseconds. So, to convert:

```
milliseconds = seconds * 1000;
seconds = milliseconds * 0.001;
```

In your case:

```
myTextBox.text = String(count1.currentCount * 1000);
```

Comment: that just parses object timer in the text box?

Comment: sorry are you wanting to convert count1.currentCount to milliseconds?

Comment: is there anyway to convert that on the fly, so myTextBox.text = count1.currentCount x 1000.toString();